# Can i get console input without echo in python?

Tags: python

Can I get console input without echo in python?

Comment: Console **input** and **echo**?  Does not compute.  Need more detail.

Comment: @Daniel I think they're using "echo" to mean "printing program inputs", similar to CMD's `@echo on`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html):

```
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> getpass()
Password:
'secret'
```

Comment: I would like character by character like getch() but cross platform

Comment: @tm1rbrt In that case, [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) is probably your best option.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could also import the `readline` module. The docs of `getpass` don't mention `readline`, but `readline` changes the behavior of `raw_input()`, for instance.

Answer (score 11):

There is also another solution (at least on unix systems, I don't know if this is working on Windows). Simply switch off the console output and use raw_input:

```
os.system("stty -echo")
password = raw_input('Enter Password:')
os.system("stty echo")
print "\n"
```

Comment: Be warned that `stty -echo` will persist until `stty echo` is called. This includes persisting outside the python session, should `raw_input` cause python to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ['console'](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) module is your only bet (it's kinda 'fork' of the curses module for Unix), however I haven't seen anything related to terminal echo disabling in its homepage, you might try to dig into it by yourself.

Comment: It's not that cross-platform at this point --- it only supports Windows through Windows 2000.