# Python curses - hide user input

Tags: python, curses

I am developing one app in python curses. I am using getch() method to get pressed keys.
But I can see pressed keys on screen. I can move cursor whenever I want, but after cursor I can see what user typed.

Of course, I can erase and redraw the whole screen after every pressed key, but it's blinking - that's distrubing.

Any idea how to get rid of these pressed keys? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i get console input without echo in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python)

Comment: I am using curses. Not standard terminal input.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, the same techniques used in `getpass` might help in your situation too. It would be worth looking at, I think.

Comment: I hope, there is some solution, built in curses ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the curses class in the following way, it will solve the problem.

```
class curses_screen:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.noecho()
        self.stdscr.keypad(1)
        SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        return self.stdscr
    def __exit__(self,a,b,c):
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

with curses_screen() as stdscr:
    """
    Execution code plush getch code here
    """
```

Comment: Yes, cbreak() and noecho() is what I wanted ;) Thank you