# Stop python from keeping original input on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, terminal

I want python to take in input then print out the input with added characters in front without outputting the original input.

Example:

```
foo = input("")
print("Me: " + foo)
```

should output

```
Me: foo
```

instead of

```
foo
Me: foo
```

I can't just do `input("Foo: ")` as there are other threads outputting to the console and they mess up the formatting.

Comment: Try using the getpass library. As answered already here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i get console input without echo in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Erase Line string to clear the line above:

```
foo = input("")
print("\033[2K\033[1AMe: " + foo)
```

This clears the `foo` As well as the newline

```
Me: foo
```