# How to Hide 'Input()' in Python?

Tags: python, input

I'm using input() to receive a user's input but do not want it to display at all because I want to assign it to a variable right away.

For example,

[image]

My goal output is just 'Height in inches is: 78.406'. I do not want to display the entered '199'.

I do not want to use getpass as I only want to have one line of output.

Thank you!

Comment: There is only one line of output here, as well. You want the `x` to be a user defined value, so user should have provision to enter it somewhere.

Comment: How is the user supposed to know if they've made a mistake, such as accidentally typing in `100` because it's dark and they can't see the keyboard properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python

Comment: You do not need the parentheses around `input()`.

Comment: I agree with @paxdiablo.  Unless the user is typing a password, they expect to see what they're typing echoed.

Answer (score -1):

you can use cls command. (windows only)

```
import os
clear = lambda:os.system('cls')

x =  int(input())
clear()
print("height in inches : ", x*0.394)
```

Comment: `os.system('clear')` for Linux and others

Comment: Side note: this solution doesn't work with IDLE.

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: Wasn't me, so no idea why

Comment: clear screen not possible with python default idle.

Comment: The solution does not allow to type invisible input.