# How to surpress the output of `input()` in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I use `input()` in Jupyter notebook and after I put something in the input box, there is a print-out of what I inputted between the `In` and `Out` lines (5 in the middle in the example). Is there a way that `input()` wouldn't print that out?

[image]

Comment: Does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python) answer your question? From what I understand the problem is that input will echo whatever you type. I don't know how this will work on a notebok though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate this is for demo only. when I do `x=input()`, there is still a print-out and I am trying to find a way to surpress that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. However, these are actually suppressing the output line instead of the middle print. Am I having a wrong setting if you could reproduce on your end?

Comment: @JohnM. My apologies. I misinterpreted what you were asking.

Comment: I suspect that display is produced by the system `readline` that echos your `stdin` to `stdout`.  The `input` docs says the `prompt`, if any, is written to `stdout`.  You might be able to get around this by temporarily redirecting `sys.stdout`.