I can't print user-input for input() in next line
I want to execute:-
print(input('Hey,how are you doing ???\\n'));

The user-ipout is:-
I am doing good, thanks.....
Oo execution i get:-
Hey,how are you doing ???I am doing good, thanks.....
I am doing good, thanks.....

I tried getting the user-input in the next line only,
but i get user-input outputted in the same line and the bext line also-2 times

that's the right behaviour, just print('Hey,how are you doing ???'); input()

The output from the input function is "Hey,how are you doing ???\n". Do you want something like answer = input('Hey,how are you doing ???\n')?

\\n should be printing a literal \n at the end of the prompt. Why isn't that shown in your sample output?

Do you not want it to echo the user's input while they're typing? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python

I just want, that on execution,- my question  is to be printed in 1st line  and the string that I input as an answer, is to be printed in the 2nd line

@SKM Then see my first comment. You used "\n" but this gives you a literal \n. You need "\n" for a line break.

If you write code as simple as:
print("Hey, how are you doing?")
print(input())

For user input "I am doing good, thanks.", the output will be:

Hey, how are you doing?
I am doing good, thanks.

However when viewing in a terminal session, you will see the user input between the two lines of output:
Hey, how are you doing?    <-- print output
I am doing good, thanks.   <-- user input
I am doing good, thanks.   <-- print output

You could avoid the intermingling of input and output by piping output to a file for receiving user input from a file. You could also use a function other than input to avoid echoing typed characters as suggested by Barmar.
Since you rarely need to echo input immediately after it's entered, you could just save the entered data into a variable.
print("Hey, how are you doing?")
user_answer = input()

That way, the only output is the question but you can keep the answer. In a terminal session, you see two lines:
Hey, how are you doing?    <-- print output
I am doing good, thanks.   <-- user input

